# How to call method which is not void in the main driver?

Tags: java, netbeans

I created the following java program in which a Statement in the form of String is taken. All the words of that statement are stored in the array separately.

Example - String statement = "hello world i love dogs";
get stored in the array as - {hello, world, i, love, dogs}

I wrote the following code, but I am not able to check it since when I call the methods in the main method, it don't work as required.

How can I get the output?

```
public class Apcsa2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */


public String sentence;

public List<Integer> getBlankPositions(){

  List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  for (int i = 0; i<sentence.length();i++){

      if(sentence.substring(i, i +1).equals(" ")){
          arr.add(i);
      }


  }


  return arr;  
}

public int countWords(){
    return getBlankPositions().size() + 1;

}

public String[] getWord(){

    int numWords = countWords();
    List<Integer> arrOfBlanks = getBlankPositions();

    String[] arr = new String[numWords];

    for (int i = 0; i<numWords; i++){

    if (i ==0){ 
    sentence.substring(i, arrOfBlanks.get(i));
    arr[i] = sentence;
    }else{

        sentence.substring(i + arrOfBlanks.get(i), arrOfBlanks.get(i+1));
        arr[i] = sentence;

    }

        }


    return arr;

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    int[] arr = {3,4,5,2,4};

    String sentence = "hello world I love dogs";
}
```

}

Comment: _I wrote the following code, but I am not able to check it since when I call the methods in the main method, it don't work as required._. Simply, make all the methods you want to call `static` or create an instance of the class `Apcsa2` inside the `main` method and invoke those methods you want executed.

Comment: You should look at standard functionality provided by `String` class if you want to `split` a string. You can look at the actual code of this method too

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, i wrote the following                                               Apcsa2 p = new Apcsa2();
        p.getWord();
        System.out.print(p);
    Still nothing is happening. So how do I input sentence and get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your objective, i think you want to count the number of words and also want to print/retrieve it. If that's the case then you don't have the complicate this that much. Use the below program.

```
public class Apcsa2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input="hello world I love dogs";

        String[] arryWords=input.split("\\s+");

        //Count-Number of words
        System.out.println("Count:"+arryWords.length);

        //Display each word separately
        for(String word:arryWords){
            System.out.println(word);
        }

    }
}
```